# Preload page on metro app store

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

I want to preload a page on my windows app store.

`Frame.Navigate` allow us to load a page in the visual tree and display this page. But I only need to load the page on the visual tree. Indeed my second page need to subscribe to some events in order to download's information. But if this page is not loaded, download started previously can't be display.

I tried to instantiate the page, but it doesn't help since `Frame.Navigate` used the type as parameters.Then I can't make the view static or used static field as each generated view is sealed.

So does it exist a solution to load page on the visual tree without display it? I didn't find any method to do it, but as I am new to .Net, I may be wrong. I was looking for a method such as :
`Frame.Preload(Type)` that I could call when the application is started.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/). It has introduced two controls `AlternativeFrame` and `AlternativePage`.

As per documentation -

> **AlternativeFrame**, **AlternativePage** - support asynchronous page
>   transitions and preloading pages so when navigation is initiated - all
>   content might already be loaded. Includes 4 built-in transitions:
>   dissolve, flip, push, wipe. You can add new ones yourself.

It does contain the method you are looking for - [AlternativeFrame.Preload()](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9c814f6c67c5#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/AlternativeFrame/AlternativeFrame.cs) to preload the pages in Visual Tree.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look.